# Toggle/Formatting with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I posted awhile ago and got great insight on hide/show text with javascript... Now I need to take this one step further. Can't find the right combination to make it work.

Here's what I **NEED**:

1. When a viewer comes to this page, the first hide/show element is displayed in the text box AND
2. That element is also highlighted a certain color to display that it is active.
3. Lastly, as every hide/show element is clicked, that stays highlighted until the next is selected.

Here's a link to my dev site. I think it's easier this way.

http://verus.exigodigital.com/services/

Here was my previous post on the hide/show text:
[Showing & Hiding Text with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15160016/showing-hiding-text-with-javascript)

REALLY appreciate the help, guys! :)

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You could make 2 CSS definitions, one for the currently selected textbox, and one for textboxes that aren't selected
When someone clicks on one of the textboxes to edit its contents (the onfocus event), you just call a function that runs through all of your textboxes, and for each one checks if it's the one with focus - if it is, set the className variable of the element to "selected" or something, and it it's not the one with focus then set it's className variable to "normal" or something
If I didn't understand the question or you need more info, just let me know :)

Comment: its not a 'textbox' the viewer can't edit anything. its not an input form. just toggling information for them to view....

Comment: In that case you can create 2 div elements in the same place, 1 visible and 1 hidden, and switch which one is visible and which one is hidden when they get clicked on